Find the position of a digit/number in a cell
In column I of my file, I have the name of clubs with a number that can take any value.
I would like to be able to retrieve the name of the club only: for this, I thought I would retrieve the position of the number that follows and then extract the character string.
My problem: I don't know how I can "easily" find the position of a number in a cell.

One way is by using a formula using built-in functions:
=FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d"), A1)

REGEXEXTRACT extracts the first digit, 0 to 9, using the regular expression \d, and then FIND is used to find and return the position of that digit.
You can easily find the details of the referred functions on the Google Sheets web app directly in the formula bar. Also, you can easily find the list of built-in functions in the Help menu. It shows like this:


Array Formula
=IFNA(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(I:I, "(.*?)\d")))

IFNA  INDEX  REGEXEXTRACT

REGEXEXTRACT is nested within INDEX so that it behaves as an array formula and is applied to all rows in the range (Column I in this example).
The regular expression  (.*?)\d translates to:

Capture Group (.*?)

. matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)


\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])


IFNA returns an empty value if the regular expression finds no digit.

See:    Regular Expressions 101
Discard spaces preceding the number
=IFNA(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(I:I, "(.*?)\s*\d"))))


Added \s* to the regular expression:

\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)



Alternative using TRIM
=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(I:I, "(.*?)\d")))))

TRIM
